# How can I use SimpleType in a WSDL data contract?

Tags: wcf, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I use a wsdl file to generate web service with the help of svcutil but it generates class  instead of simple int or string parameter for the service contract.
What I did:

1. I created a WCF Service Application
2. I created a Console Application then added the service reference to the project
3. I used svcutil.exeto generate service from thy wsdl and xsd files in console project

Why does it do that and how I can rewrite the wsdl to solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you used `/messageContract` switch in svcutil.

If you added service via service reference, then right click on service->configure service reference and uncheck `Always generate message contracts`